# Convert Value Of String to a type In C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a String variable that Contain A type
for Example :

```
String StrType ="Int32"; // Or "Decimal" Or Char Or an Enum Color
```

I want To Make new Variable with Type StrType (Value Of StrType)

in this example I Want To Have this Variable :

```
Int32 MyType;
```

I dont Want To use swich or if...else to detect the type because
Not This -->

```
If (StrType=="Int32")
   Int32 MyType;
```

(the other word I have a Type Name in StrType I Want to Make A New Variable with 
It type In Runtime)

What Can I Do This ?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `Type.GetType(StrType)` - this will get you a Type variable containing corresponding type. If you want to get an *object instance* of StrType then you'll need to use a bit of reflection, like this:

```
    var t = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    var constructor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    object intObject = constructor.Invoke(null); //intObject will have type System.Int32
```

Of course, this will work only if the type is successfully resolved and if parameterless constructor exists for that type. In production you should add checks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but try `Type.GetType("System.Int32");`

Comment: That won't work - it has to be a namespace-qualified type name, to start with: `"System.Int32"` would work, but `"Int32"` wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate to call the String, Int32, and other constructors.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

`// get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");`